# Django: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{

Tags: html, django, if-statement, error-handling, nested

When I execute my HTML Code, it gives me the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

I tried to nest the conditions too, but I am an absolute beginner in HTML so I wanted to get this version at least correct, but it is not working...

```
{% block content %}
<p align="justify"> So far you donated {{ donated_trees }} Tree(s).  </p>
 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' %}
    Your current position is {{ player.end_position }} of {{ anzahlspieler }} for the most donated trees.
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and {{ player.rival }} == 0 %}
<P>     No other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and {{ player.rival }} == 1 %}
<P>     One other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

{% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and {{ player.rival }} > 1 %}
<P>     {{ player.rival }} other players have the same.</P>
{% endif %}
```

The error occurs from line 8 on.

Answer (score 2):

You can *not* use `{{ … }}` *within* a template tag, just use the variable itself:

```
{% block content %}
<p align="justify"> So far you donated {{ donated_trees }} Tree(s).  </p>
 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' %}
    Your current position is {{ player.end_position }} of {{ anzahlspieler }} for the most donated trees.
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and player.rival == 0 %}
<P>     No other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and player.rival == 1 %}
<P>     One other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

{% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and player.rival > 1 %}
<P>     {{ player.rival }} other players have the same.</P>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line as well as the answers like it.

```
 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and {{ player.rival }} == 0 %}
```

When you are using a variable in the `{% %}` tags, you just put the variable by itself, like `player.rival`, not like this `{{ player.rival }}`.

Full working code:

```
{% block content %}
<p align="justify"> So far you donated {{ donated_trees }} Tree(s).  </p>
 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' %}
    Your current position is {{ player.end_position }} of {{ anzahlspieler }} for the most donated trees.
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and player.rival == 0 %}
<P>     No other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

 {% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and player.rival == 1 %}
<P>     One other player has the same.</P>
{% endif %}

{% if treatmentgroup == 'two' or treatmentgroup == 'three' and  player.rival > 1 %}
<P>     {{ player.rival }} other players have the same.</P>
{% endif %}
```